# EWS manages APIs - Is there a way to get deleted events from a calendar?

Tags: calendar, exchangewebservices, office365api

I am writing a client to sync all items of user's mailbox(including calendars, contacts) with my application. Here I want to capture, all creation, updates and deletions for all items. Although, Office 365 has calendarview API(with change tracking) to sync calendar events, I am facing following issue with the same:

1. With calendarview, we need to specify a time range for events.
2. Calendarview API gives recurrence events in expanded form. And does not give deleted occurrences from recurrence events. You need to parse all occurrences to figure out the deleted occurrences.

With the above limitations, it becomes difficult to sync calendar events for a long period of time.

**Hence, I would really appreciate if someone can point to a solution for the following:**

1. Is there an EWS API to fetch deleted items(or only their ids) from a calendar? Here, I want only the list of events not in expanded form.
2. Any way to get deleted occurrences from a recurrence master event?
3. Any better way to synchronize calendar events from Exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have for it is:

1. Use SyncFolderItems to synchronize the calendar as any other folder. It returns all items in non-expanded form.
2. To get deleted occurrences of a recurring event: Use GetItem call with RecurringMasterId and few additional properties like calendar.DeletedOccurrences.

Answer (score 1):

So if you app can run all the time (or most of the time), you can use either Push, Pull, or [Streaming](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2010/12/22/working-with-streaming-notifications-by-using-the-ews-managed-api/) notifications to get an event sent to your app whenever anything changes on a calendar, including deletions.  (Streaming is the preferred method these days.)  There also is a [Sync feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693003(v=exchg.80).aspx) in EWS that I have never used, but might be applicable here as well.  My experience has been that when you get deleted notifications, the item in question cannot be retrieved by the ItemId in the notification, since it is *gone,* even if it's actually been moved to Deleted Items.  Deleted instances of recurring meetings are even harder to track down, and I'm not sure whether the notification contains the actual instance id or the master id.

Comment: The problem is, I cannot run my app all the time & hence cant use streaming notifications.
Thanks for suggesting Sync Feature, I tried it and it can be used to sync items of calendar.